# Line breaks in textareas in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the value of a textarea based on an existing array but I want the array items to be separated by a new line on the textarea. I want the textarea to have the items on the unordered list so that I can make a button that can copy the textarea's content into the clipboard.

I get this error: Expecting Unicode escape sequence \uXXXX I think because of the \n. I really don't know what else to do. Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
class NamesList extends Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

 }

 render(){
  const RenderedNames = this.props.formattedNames.map((name, index) => {
   return <li key={index} >{name}</li>
  });

  const formattedNamesBreak = this.props.formattedNames.map((name, index) => {
   return name \n
  });

  return(
   <div>
   <ul className='media-list list-group'>
    {RenderedNames}
   </ul>
   <textarea className='hidden' readOnly='true' value={formattedNamesBreak}></textarea>
   </div>
  );
 }
 
};


export default NamesList;
```

Comment: `return name \n` is a syntax error. Just curious, did you mean to put this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your array is an array of strings (the names), you don't need to `map()` because that would create a resulting array and if you try to output an array as the textarea value, it will be converted to a string with commas to separate the values.

The solution is to call [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array and use a new line as the "glue":

```
var formattedNamesBreak = this.props.formattedNames.join('\n');
```